# Considering three numbers, nr_1, nr_2, and nr_3. How can write a program such that nr_1 has the largest value and nr_3 the smallest

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, bubble-sort

The three numbers are variables and can have any value. The program should just assign the largest of the number to nr_1 and smallest to nr_3

Comment: Please provide more context and a minimum reproducible example

Comment: perform checks and update the variables........

Comment: You will have to provide more details of your problem (preferably something that is reproducible) along with some code that you have tried. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information on how to formulate your question.

Comment: Can we safely assume that tagging [tag:pyth] was a mistake?

Comment: @khelwood I think yes. I've edited the tags

Answer (score 0):

> You should be more specific an provide more details about the problem which you want to solve as described in the comments.

I will try to answer the question:
As you want to find the `maximum` and `minimum` of the 3 values which the variable stores, and as given the variable can store any type of values, I will suggest you represent each of the value as a string and compare them lexicographically.

You don't need to use `bubble-sort` for this task in `python`, as you can use `max` and `min` functions in `python`.

```py
def main():
    v1, v2, v3 = tuple(input().rstrip().split())
    nr_1 = (max(v1, v2, v3))
    nr_2 = (min(v1, v2, v3))
    print(nr_1, nr_2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[Try Online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7BCsMgEETv@YolpxVCQW1pKPgti1BDhbgVY0L79daYQw5dWFh2ZpgXv/n1Zl3K000QrGcUjw7qbHKATdXVYCCvcXboOa4ZxSUtOflYjyXOvj5EC3AiWa0Y7AfP8CmqJtaCPzEmzxn3/NCMouv8BERsgyMCY6An2tmI@gPuAC3lPo5XuElQSv8A).

Although if you are specific about the type of data in the 3 variables you defined, then you need to adjust your program accordingly.